# How can I add two values with numeric type in function with kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, generics

i wanna sum 2 Int or 2 Double with using Generic.

```
fun <T> someFunction(a: T,b: T) {
    Log.d(TAG, "${a+b}") 
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what situation would this come in handy? There's no trivial solution for this, but I've never come across a need for it. Usually you know the types of numbers that you're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inline fun <reified T : Number> someFunction(a: T, b: T): T? {
  return when {
    a is Int && b is Int       -> (a.toInt() + b.toInt()) as T
    a is Double && b is Double -> (a.toDouble() + b.toDouble()) as T
    else                       -> null
  }
}

val resultInt = someFunction(2, 3)           // value: 5   , type: Int?
val resultDouble = someFunction(2.25, 3.5)   // value: 5.75, type: Double?
val resultMixed = someFunction(2, 3.5)       // value: null, type: Number?
```

Comment: This doesn't need to be reified/inline since you're type checking the parameters instead of using `T::class`.

Comment: Without reified you could not safely cast to T.

Comment: You can safely cast, it's just an unchecked cast because the compiler doesn't know it's safe. The reason I bring it up is that whatever use case would require a generic version of a summing function is not going to be able to call a reified function. If you already knew the types at compile time such that you could call a reified function, you could simply use `+` instead of this function.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no good way to do this.

While [Number](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/) is a superclass of the numeric types, it's underspecified — all it lets you do is *convert* the value to one of the standard numeric types. It *doesn't* provide any way to to do arithmetic or other numeric operations.

(That may be because the types don't work. In traditional languages with many numeric types, such as C and Java, the result of an operation has a type which depends on both the operand types: adding a `short` and an `int` gives an `int` result. But there's no way to express that for class methods.)

So if you want to handle any `Number`, there are probably two approaches you can take.

Since the only thing `Number` provides is conversion it to a specific numeric type, **one approach is to convert to the ‘best’ type, and do your arithmetic in that type**. For example, if you only care about integer values, then you can call `toLong()` and do all your arithmetic with `Long`s.

For example:

```
fun <T> someFunction(a: T,b: T) {
    Log.d(TAG, "${a.toLong() + b.toLong()}")
}
```

But this isn't a good general solution, because in general there isn't a ‘best’ type — whichever type you choose, there are some values it can't store. (`Long` is the largest integral type, but can't store fractions. And `Double` is the largest floating-point type, but can't store the full precision of `Longs` — for example, both `Long.MAX_VALUE` and `Long.MAX-VALUE - 1` convert to the same `Double` value.) So whichever type you choose will risk some form of imprecision or rounding.

**The other approach is to see which concrete types you have, and handle each combination separately.** For example:

For example:

```
fun <T> someFunction(a: T,b: T) {
    if ((a is Long && (b is Long || b is Int || b is Char || b is Short || b is Byte))
    || (b is Long && (a is Long || a is Int || a is Char || a is Short || a is Byte)))
        Log.d(TAG, "${a.toLong() + b.toLong()}")
    else if ((a is Int && (b is Int || b is Char || b is Short || b is Byte))
    || (b is Int && (a is Int || a is Char || a is Short || a is Byte)))
        Log.d(TAG, "${a.toInt() + b.toInt()}")
    else if ((a is Short && (b is Short || b is Byte))
    || (b is Short && (a is Short || a is Byte)))
        Log.d(TAG, "${a.toShort() + b.toShort()}")
    // …and so on, for all the other combinations you want to handle…
}
```

This gives you much finer control; but it's rarely used because it's far too long-winded and unwieldy for most situations. (And it won't cope with any new subclasses of `Number` that people write.)

So there's no good general approach to handling numbers in a generic fashion.

Instead, there are two specific approaches that people tend to take:

1. **Pick a single concrete type, and use that.** Often the requirements of your code dictate a suitable type (e.g. `Int`), and while it's nice to be generic, that's often not strictly needed.
2. **Provide a `Long` version and a `Double` version.** Between them, those types can hold all possible values from all the built-in numeric types, so one or other is normally sufficient for any particular use.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you

```
fun <T: Number> someFunction(a: T,b: T) {
    val result =  (a.toDouble()+b.toDouble()) as T
    Log.d(TAG, "$result")
}
```

or if you want to return it

```
fun <T: Number> someFunction(a: T,b: T): T {
    return (a.toDouble()+b.toDouble()) as T
}
```

Comment: Won't there be loss of precision for very large ints when using _toDouble()_?

Comment: @lukas.j I didn't think of that. you're probably right

Comment: i dont want cast it to double i want if it was Int return int and if it was  Double return Double .

Comment: @EMJEY it does return in Int if you input two Ints. that's what `as T` does

Comment: It's not safe to cast the result to T. If it is assigned to an `Int?` and then used elsewhere, it will crash. It's is only through some runtime implementation quirk that this can survive boxing as a `Double` known to the compiler a `T` and unboxing to an `Int`. https://pl.kotl.in/pboNGcEiK