# How to define function, which accepts all numerics in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, numbers

What I thought didn't work

```
fun compute1(x: Double, y:Double) : Double {
    return x + y
}

fun compute2(x: Number, y:Number) : Number {
    return x + y // can't use plus
}

fun main() {
    compute1(12, 13) // cant use integers
}
```

How to accomplish?

---

Solution should be as laconic as in java

```
public class MathEx {
   public static double compute(double x, double y) {
      return x+y;
   }
}
```

Comment: [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/) doesn't have a `plus` operation so this won't work generically. I can think of some alternatives (passing in a method reference, e.g. `fun <N : Number> compute(x: N, y: N, operation: (N, N) -> N): N = operation(x, y)`, or using a `when` statement to get the appropriate `::plus` - but these aren't very pretty. More context would help understand what you want to achieve. Why do you want to generically operate on numbers?

Comment: I regard the wish to generically operate on numbers as sotheing that is not required to be explained. What is the purpose of all other improvements in a language if generality of numbers is lost?

Comment: The update to your question gives me more of an idea. I'd recommend using `BigDecimal`. Kotlin has some [nice extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-decimal/) to make using them as easy as any other number. Is using [`toBigDecimal()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-big-decimal.html) something you'd considered?

Comment: Kotlin does not make assumptions about which direction you want to “promote” numbers when doing arithmetic with different types because it is an enormous source of bugs in Java. Better conciseness is not a goal of the Kotlin designers. More readable and robust code is the goal. This often means more concise syntax, but in this case it is less concise. I know I’ve been burned in Java before by passing an int as a float accidentally, or calling a wrong overload because of number types.

Comment: Another example of this sort is that `when` in Kotlin and `switch` in C# don’t allow fall-through behavior like in Java’s `switch`, since it is a known major source of bugs, even though it makes certain logic less concise.

Comment: See [my answer](/a/70621965/10134209) to [this related question](/questions/70619785/how-can-i-add-two-values-with-numeric-type-in-function-with-kotlin/70621965#70621965).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add two values with numeric type in function with kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70619785/how-can-i-add-two-values-with-numeric-type-in-function-with-kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

You could overload the function to receive the combinations that you want

```
fun compute(x:Double, y:Double) = x + y
fun compute(x:Float, y:Float) = x + y
fun compute(x:Int, y:Int) = x + y
fun compute(x:Double, y:Int) = x + y
fun compute(x:Float, y:Int) = x + y

fun main() {
    compute(12, 13)
}
```

Quite verbose, or you can define just one or two and convert the number before calling the function, which is not very efficient but it would work

```
fun compute(x:Double, y:Double) = x + y

fun main() {
    compute(12.toDouble(), 13.toDouble())
}
```

from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#floating-point-types

> Note that unlike some other languages, there are no implicit widening conversions for numbers in Kotlin. For example, a function with a Double parameter can be called only on Double values, but not Float, Int, or other numeric values.

Comment: try `compute1(12.0, 13.0f)`

Comment: also imagine the function is 5-variate

Comment: the `toDouble` was just to be clear, is this a practical problem or is it just for you to better understand the language?

Comment: I need to understand a language and decide, how mature and perspective it is

Comment: Kotlin strictly doesnt allow for implicit widening, because in all languages that do allow it, it is a source for a lot of bugs, take javascript and java as an example, javascript going even a step worse with its type coercions. In the case of java, you can accidentally lose precision or accidentally cast numeral types to others implicitely, which is counterintuitive for the developer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution since there are examples where you get rounding errors but for your use case this might be good enough

```
fun compute2(x: Number, y:Number) : Double{
    return x.toDouble() + y.toDouble()
}
```